# How to reuse code to track runs of pieces on a triangular board in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a project in Python, and part of it involves ranking board states in a game. This game, Sneaky Statues, is similar to Connect Four, in which you win by getting four pieces in a row. My naive estimation of a board is how many pieces you have in a row (so either 1, 2, 3 or 4.) The board is a triangle, so you can have pieces in a row horizontally, or diagonally in either direction. This is the function I'm using right now to find runs of pieces.

```
def score(player):

    player_x = sorted(player, key=lambda statue: statue.x) #player's pieces sorted by x coordinate
    player_y = sorted(player, key=lambda statue: statue.y)
    max_score = [0]

    count = 1
    #pieces are in a horizontal line if they share a y coord and have sequential x coords
    for cur_s, next_s in zip(player_x, player_x[1:]):
        if cur_s.x + 1 == next_s.x and cur_s.y == next_s.y:
            count += 1
        else:
            max_score.append(count)
            count = 1
    max_score.append(count)

    count = 1
    #pieces are diagonal if they share an x and have sequential y's
    for cur_s, next_s in zip(player_y, player_y[1:]):
        if cur_s.y + 1 == next_s.y and cur_s.x == next_s.x:
            count += 1
        else:
            max_score.append(count)
            count = 1
    max_score.append(count)

    count = 1
    #they are diagonal if both x's and y's are sequential
    for cur_s, next_s in zip(player_y, player_y[1:]):
        if cur_s.y + 1 == next_s.y and cur_s.x + 1 == next_s.x:
            count += 1                                                                                                                                                               
        else:
            max_score.append(count)
            count = 1
    max_score.append(count)

    return max(max_score)
```

As far as I can tell, it's working, but I'm essentially repeating myself three times. My question is, what is the most Pythonic way for me to write this function so that I repeat myself less?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely not the best but at first sight I see that you can combine all the loops into a single function that has three arguments:

```
def score(player):

    player_x = sorted(player, key=lambda statue: statue.x) #player's pieces sorted by x coordinate
    player_y = sorted(player, key=lambda statue: statue.y)
    max_score = [0]

    def take_count(player, x_offset, y_offset):
        count = 1
        for cur_s, next_s in zip(player, player[1:]):
            if cur_s.x + x_offset == next_s.x and cur_s.y + y_offset == next_s.y:
                count += 1
            else:
                max_score.append(count)
                count = 1
        max_score.append(count)

    #pieces are in a horizontal line if they share a y coord and have sequential x coords
    take_count(player_x, 1, 0)

    #pieces are diagonal if they share an x and have sequental y's
    take_count(player_y, 0, 1)

    #they are diagonal if both x's and y's are sequential
    take_count(player_y, 1, 1)

    return max(max_score)
```